# Conditional contextMenus depending on site

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm am working on a little chrome extension which uses the contextMenu to add an option or two when the user right clicks a webpage. However, this is only relevant of a few webpages out there and I would like to only show the additional menu item when it is relevant.

I would therefore like a way to get the current URL in my background page and see if the URL matches any of the sites in my whitelist.

I've googled a bit around but I'm not sure this is even possible. Any help would be appreciated, and please do not spare me for the details - JavaScript is not my strong side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DevGuide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html)

```
chrome.contextMenus.create(object createProperties, function callback)
```

**Parameters**

```
createProperties ( object )

type ( optional enumerated string ["normal", "checkbox", "radio", "separator"] )
```

The type of menu item. Defaults to 'normal' if not specified.

```
title ( optional string )
```

The text to be displayed in the item; this is required unless type is 'separator'. When the context is 'selection', you can use %s within the string to show the selected text. For example, if this parameter's value is "Translate '%s' to Pig Latin" and the user selects the word "cool", the context menu item for the selection is "Translate 'cool' to Pig Latin".

```
checked ( optional boolean )
```

The initial state of a checkbox or radio item: true for selected and false for unselected. Only one radio item can be selected at a time in a given group of radio items.

```
contexts ( optional array of string ["all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio"] )
```

List of contexts this menu item will appear in. Defaults to ['page'] if not specified.

```
parentId ( optional integer )
```

The ID of a parent menu item; this makes the item a child of a previously added item.

```
documentUrlPatterns ( optional array of string )
```

**Lets you restrict the item to apply only to documents whose URL matches one of the given patterns. (This applies to frames as well.) For details on the format of a pattern, see Match Patterns.**

```
targetUrlPatterns ( optional array of string )
```

Similar to documentUrlPatterns, but lets you filter based on the src attribute of img/audio/video tags and the href of anchor tags.

```
onclick ( optional function )
```

A function that will be called back when the menu item is clicked.

**Parameters**

```
info ( OnClickData )
```

Information about the item clicked and the context where the click happened.

```
tab ( Tab )
```

The details of the tab where the click took place.